# is the last day included in when we talk about booking a place from one day to another?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, dates

> We have reserved a room **from 1 April to 1 June 2020.**

Does that mean that one should check out on the 1st or the 2nd of June 2020?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about English but about booking practices.

Comment: They should check out on the 2nd of June. Hotel reservations are about nights rather than daytime. So, the last date does not include the night of that date. It only shows you the check-out day.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You checkout on the 1st of June 2020.

**Go on any room booking site**, as I just did. See on the left that I was asking to check-in on the 9th and check-out on the 10th. Your question is whether that makes one day or two days. Look on the far right and see $200 for 1 night.